# How to add a conditional statement in markdown?

Tags: if-statement, markdown

I am trying to conditionally show a header depending whether any object is present in a list or not. I can't understand how to do it in markdown.

I want my code to show the Heading "Dancers" if and only if any dancers are present in dancers_list

```
#Dancers

{% include dancers_list.md %}
```

```
if((dancers_list.md)=[]){
  #Dancers
  {% include dancers_list.md %}
```

How is something like this possible?

Comment: Markdown is a markup language, not a programming language. You'd be better off writing a program in an appropriate language which generates a Markdown document as its output.